# Nested data, associations, form, grid, combobox and update data?

Tags: extjs, combobox, nested, associations, cancellation

All is in the title !
I am using a nested data (json) to populate a form and some grids :

My data :

```
AqiConfig : root
    Id
    Label
    Type : unique
        Id
        Label 
    Pollutants : hasMany
        Id
        Optional
        Tag physical
```

[The fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2bha&view/editor)

If you click in a row of the first grid (aqiGrid) then the following components are filled.

**First trouble:** in *aqiForm*, if I modify the label then click on Cancel it's OK but if I modify the Type using the combobox the cancel button is not working. Any idea to solve this ?

**Second trouble:** in the *aqiPollutantGrid* (under the form). The last column permits to change the physical value of the pollutant. The store of the combobox lists available physicals.

- If I try to change the physical, the current physical disapeared
- If I choose a new physical in the list, the new physical is not selected, the first one appeared. I found a way to soluce that using the change event but I thnik that's not the good way.
- What is the good way to cancel this action and restore the original config values ? I found a way using the rejectChanges() function : it's ok for the *Optional* field but an error appeared for the combobox

Thanks for your help !

Marc